# ls: how do I list directories sorted by timestamps of the files it contains

Tags: ls

How do I list directories by their access time in the sense that some new files/directories are created (say, directories containing the most recently created files).

Comment: Run `man ls` for a full list of options including various sort possibilities.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There are a couple of options that you can combine.

The `-c` switch sorts by time modified [1]:

> **-c**     with  *-lt*: sort by, and show, ctime (time of last modification of file status information) with *-l*: show ctime and sort by name otherwise:
>               sort by ctime

The `-u` and `-t` switches can also be used:

> **-t**     sort by modification time
> **-u**     with *-lt*: sort by, and show, access time with *-l*: show access time and sort by name otherwise: sort by access time

You could put it all together like so [2]:

```
ls -ltcr         # sort by and show change time, most recent last
ls -ltur         # sort by and show access time, most recent last
ls -ltr          # sort by date, most recent last
```

[1] http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ls

[2] `-r` reverses the order